# mach memory mapped files

Tags: ios, darwin, mach

*Apple:*

> The VM calls available to an application include vm_map and
>   vm_allocate, which can be used to map file data or anonymous memory
>   into the address space

Trying to memory map some files in iOS by dropping down to mach level - trouble finding documentation.

Specifically, trying to find out how to create a `memory_object_t` using a given file, which I can then use with `vm_map()`.